# What are St. Thomas Aquinas's views on fatherhood?

Tags: thomas-aquinas

What are St. Thomas Aquinas's views on fatherhood? Did he define fatherhood (*paternitas*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 102](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS102.html#SSQ102A1THEP1) (on the virtue of observance) [a. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS102.html#SSQ102A1THEP1) co. is a very good, concise/precise definition of fatherhood, typical for St. Thomas:

> just as a carnal father partakes of the character of **principle** in a particular way, which character is found in God in a universal way, so too a person who, in some way, exercises **providence** in one respect, partakes of the character of father in a particular way, since a father is the **principle** of **generation**, of **education**, of **learning** and of whatever pertains to the **perfection of human life**
> <sub>Sicut autem carnalis pater particulariter participat rationem **principii**, quae universaliter invenitur in Deo; ita etiam persona quae quantum ad aliquid **providentiam** circa nos gerit, particulariter participat proprietatem patris, quia pater est **principium** et **generationis** et **educationis** et **disciplinae**, et omnium quae ad **perfectionem humanae vitae pertinent**.</sub>

I've always liked the relationship between *principio* or [ἀρχή](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/51741/2014) (principle/beginning) and *princeps* (prince). I wonder if these words are etymologically related to *pater*. It seems characteristic of manly thinking to be principled, favoring deduction over induction.